# c++ argv argument not parsing * from command line

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments

I have an issue with a `*` character in my command line input.

The commands are these:

```
2.exe input.txt output.txt + 2
2.exe input.txt output.txt - 2
2.exe input.txt output.txt * 2
```

It all works perfectly, except the last one. Somehow it does not get the `*` character from the command line. If I put `'*'` it works, but that is not the idea.

I searched all the web, and the closest I got was some globals being mentioned somewhere, but not sure how to do it. Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{

    ifstream infile(argv[1]);
    ofstream outfile(argv[2]);



    if (infile.is_open() && infile.good()) {
        int num;
        int sum = 0;
        string arg = string(argv[3]);
        int val = atoi(argv[4]);


        while(infile >> num)
        {

        if(arg == "+") sum = num + val;
        else if(arg == "-") sum = num - val;
        else sum = num * val;



        cout << "SUM: " << num << endl;
        cout << "SUM: " << sum << endl;
        outfile << sum << " ";
        }

        outfile.close();


    } else {
        cout << "Faila ne se otvarq";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you on some kind of Unix system? Most likely Linux? Then `*` is a special character, that expands to match file names. This happens before it ever touches your program. Search for "globbing".

Comment: What is your question? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Regarding the comment from @BoBTFish, that might be true in Unix-like environments in Windows as well, like MSYS or Cygwin.

Comment: I am using Windows 7 cmd

Answer (score 6):

because of [Shell expansion](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_03_04.html), `*` is expanded by the shell into all files in the current directory, you should use either

```
2.exe input.txt output.txt '*' 2
```

or

```
2.exe input.txt output.txt \* 2
```

Comment: I figured that out myself. But thought there is another way to preserve the input:
    2.exe input.txt output.txt \* 2

Comment: @bruno The problem is not in your code, nor in the code generated by the compiler.  It's caused solely by the shell command line interface that is responsible for this behaviour.  For example, on windows, the command line doesn't expland `*` on its own.  Or if you would call your programme with `execvp()` it wold work as you expect.

Comment: Ok, so nothing I can do I guess. Right?

Comment: @bruno guess it's not much extra work to use `'*'` or `\*` instead of `*`

Comment: I know, it is my homework, so it seems like a trap from the teacher :)